# Must Match two different terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to filter results where two sets of data match
I get hits when I specify "should" but not "must"
Here is my query works as expected with just the one "match" but if I add a second I get no hits yet there are definitely records in the index that have productSpecification.value of Brand and 3 Years

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "control*",
        "fields": [
          "name^15",
          "description^5",
          "productCode"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

```
"post_filter": {
"nested": {
  "path": "productSpecification",
  "query": {
    "bool":{
        "must": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "productSpecification.value":"3 years"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "productSpecification.value":"Brand"
                }
            }
        ]           
    }        
  }
  }
}
```

}

Just banging my head against the desk now trying different combinations of JSON trying to get this to return some values

```
{
"myindex": {
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "description": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dispatchTimeInDays": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "height": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "html": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "leadTimeInDays": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "length": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "limitedStock": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "notes": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "price": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "productBrandId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "productCategory": {
                    "properties": {
                        "code": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "fullPath": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "parentProductCategoryId": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "productCategoryId": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "productCategoryId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "productCode": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "productId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "productImage": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "productSpecification": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "productId": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "productSpecificationId": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "specificationId": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "productTypeId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "reviewRating": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "reviewRatingCount": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "sellingPriceGroupId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "stockAvailable": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "taxRateId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "weightKg": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "width": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is an example of a product I would expect to be returned with this query it has a productSpecification.value of "3 years" AND a productSpecification.value of "Brand"

```
{
"_index": "myindex",
"_type": "product",
"_id": "uQEDbGEBfHre1rYmtsWB",
"_score": 141.5985,
"_source": {
    "productId": 14587,
    "name": "Brand Wave Multi Channel Remote Control",
    "productCode": "111",
    "productCategoryId": 17,
    "length": 3,
    "height": 0,
    "productTypeId": 1,
    "url": "brand-wave-multi-channel-remote-control",
    "productBrandId": 3,
    "width": 0,
    "dispatchTimeInDays": 3,
    "leadTimeInDays": 3,
    "stockAvailable": 0,
    "weightKg": 0.001,
    "reviewRatingCount": 0,
    "limitedStock": false,
    "price": 63,
    "productImage": "Wave-Remote-Control.jpg",
    "productCategory": {
        "productCategoryId": 17,
        "name": "Accessories",
        "fullPath": "Accessories",
        "code": "00011"
    },
    "productSpecification": [{
            "productSpecificationId": 852888,
            "productId": 14587,
            "specificationId": 232,
            "name": "Brand",
            "description": "This is the product manufacturer",
            "value": "Brand"
        },
        {
            "productSpecificationId": 852889,
            "productId": 14587,
            "specificationId": 92,
            "name": "Type",
            "value": "Remote control"
        },
        {
            "productSpecificationId": 852891,
            "productId": 14587,
            "specificationId": 10,
            "name": "Guarantee",
            "value": "3 years"
        },
        {
            "productSpecificationId": 852892,
            "productId": 14587,
            "specificationId": 599,
            "name": "Power Voltage",
            "value": "1.5 V"
        },
        {
            "productSpecificationId": 852893,
            "productId": 14587,
            "specificationId": 29,
            "name": "Dimensions",
            "value": "157mm x 38mm x 19mm"
        },
        {
            "productSpecificationId": 852894,
            "productId": 14587,
            "specificationId": 602,
            "name": "Operation Range",
            "value": "Up to 40m"
        },
        {
            "productSpecificationId": 852895,
            "productId": 14587,
            "specificationId": 601,
            "name": "Power Supply",
            "value": "3V DC; 2 x AAA batteries"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

After numerous amends my query is now like

```
{
"size": 100,


"aggs": {
    "specifications": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "productSpecification"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "groups": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "productSpecification.name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "attribute": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "productSpecification.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "price_range": {
      "range": {
        "field": "price",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 50
          },
          {
            "from": 50,
            "to": 100
          },
          {
            "from": 100,
            "to": 150
          },
          {
            "from": 150,
            "to": 200
          },
          {
            "from": 200,
            "to": 250
          },
          {
            "from": 250
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "control*",
            "fields": [
              "name^15",
              "description^5",
              "productCode"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "query":{
    "nested": {
      "path": "productSpecification",
      "query": {
        "bool":{
            "should": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must":[{
                        "term": {
                            "productSpecification.name.keyword": "Brand"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "productSpecification.value": "Brand"
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "productSpecification.name.keyword": "Guarantee"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "productSpecification.value": "3 years"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
      }
      }
    }
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: could you post your index mapping GET /<your_index_name>/_mapping ?

Comment: Mapping now added thanks for having a look

Comment: Hi Is it that my Mapping/Index is not structured in an optimal way to achieve what I want, Basically I need to be able to create aggregations from the product specifications and then filter on them as you would see on most eCommerce sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working after lots of experimentation / reading
posting here in case it is of use to others with similar problems

```
{

"post_filter": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [{
                "nested": {
                    "path": "productSpecification",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "productSpecification.name": "Brand"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "productSpecification.value": [
                                            "Brand1"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "productSpecification",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "productSpecification.name": "Guarantee"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "productSpecification.value": [
                                            "3 years"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

productSpecification.value is a keyword datatype. You should query against it with term query instead of match. And then you can't use must because if a doc has brand as value can't have also 3 years as value. In your case you will use should, because is an OR logical operator

```
    {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "productSpecification",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "productSpecification.name.keyword": "Brand"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "productSpecification.value": "Brand"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "productSpecification.name.keyword": "Guarantee"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "productSpecification.value": "3 years"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sorry should have mentioned in the original question I have tried with both term and match same result of 0 hits

Comment: could you provide an example of productSpecification.value content? With the keyword datatype you create a single token with the content of the field. So if the content is " brand 3 year" and you search for "brand" you will not find anything because the field doesn't subdivided its content in tokens. You could retrieve the doc only if you search the exact phrase " brand 3 year". If this is your case you have to change your mapping

Comment: Hi I have added a sample "Hit" that I would expect to return

Comment: i have updated my answer. You can't use must in your case. Is an OR case

Comment: I am aware I can get this to return hits with a should but then it isnt filtering the results correctly, I am using this for a website product search, a customer will want to filter down their results by selecting for example Guarantee = "3 years" Brand ="Brand" and Operation Range = "40m"

Comment: can't understand you... why the query isn't filtering the results correctly? if you want that the customer could filter for that keys, why you haven't insert them in your index?

Comment: ah, ok. now i understand. But was not clear previously. I will update my answer

Comment: I have the items I want to filter on within productSpecification it may be that I have set my index up incorrectly Different types of product have different types of specification available so this was my best guess as to how to build my index

Comment: Hi thats looking like what I need but get the following error from ES

[must] query malformed, no start_object after query name

Comment: ah sure, damn. I forget the squared brackets after should clause. I have updated my answer

Comment: It now complains that the JSON syntax is incorrect, which is a problem I was having in my experiments

Comment: Unfortunatly the same result of 0 hits (no errors now)

Comment: What's changed it looks the same?

Comment: nested clause added

Comment: I already had nested, i tried adding a query above the nested like you have and then got this error no [query] registered for [query]

Comment: Have added the query in its current state to the end of the original question

Comment: ok .keyword at the end of productSpecification.name was stopping it working alltogether, removing keyword i get results but it is behaving as before as essentially an OR statement when what i need is an AND It is returning all hits where either the brand matches or the Guarantee matches